# telerik GridCalculatedColumn with two different data types for DataFields

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have the following column setup in my Telerik Rad Grid:

```
<telerik:GridCalculatedColumn HeaderText="Remark Code" DataFields="RemarkCodeID, RemarkCodeName" Expression='{0} + " - " + {1}' DataFormatString="{0:N}" ></telerik:GridCalculatedColumn>
```

I get an error that cannot convert an Int and RemarkCodeID is an int above.  Is there a way I can convert RemarkCodeID to a string?  Also, when I replace RemarkCodeID with a data field that is of type string, no error so I know it is RemarkCodeID that is causing the error.

Error:
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'System.String Concat(System.Object, System.Object)'

Comment: If you want to convert that to a string, you might want to move away from GridCalculatedColumn and just calculate the string in the code behind and use a GridBoundColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using GridCalculatedColumn for display purposes. It is used only for calculating something and then displaying it.
What you need can be achieved by the usual GridBoundColumn. The datasource which contains the fields RemarkCodeID and RemarkCodeName should be consolidated into a single field separated by the '-' symbol. This new merged column should be the source for the column value you are trying to display.

### RemarkCodeID  |  RemarkCodeName  |  NewMergedColumn

```
 65                |          Error...       |    65 - Error...
```